# How to send email based on two tables after insert query?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email update to users from the `candidates_table` but the content of the email comes from the `jobs_list` table. Please see my attempt below, I'm using PHPmailer and I'm getting no errors. The script below is the handling script for a form.

The data from the `jobs_list` is being displayed, however, the `candidates_table` data is not.

This is just below the insert statement:

UPDATE:

```
$vac_last_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
echo $vac_last_id; 


$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE id=:id");

$sql->bindValue(':id', $vac_last_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

if($sql->execute()) {
   $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}

while($row = $sql->fetch()) { 


$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = '';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
$mail->Port =;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->setFrom('', '- Vacancies');
$mail->addReplyTo('', '- Vacancies');

$mail->Subject = "";
//Same body for all messages, so set this before the sending loop
//If you generate a different body for each recipient (e.g. you're using a templating system),
//set it inside the loop
$mail->Body = 'THE BODY...';

      //msgHTML also sets AltBody, but if you want a custom one, set it afterwards
      $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer';
      //Connect to the database and select the recipients from your mailing list that have not yet been sent to
      //You'll need to alter this to match your database

    $mysql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table WHERE receive_email = 2");
    if ($mysql->execute()) {
      $mysql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        }

foreach ($mysql as $row) { //This iterator syntax only works in PHP 5.4+

$mail->addAddress($row['email_address'], $row['full_name']);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email_address"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
    break; //Abandon sending
} else {
    echo "Message sent to :" . $row['full_name'] . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row['email_address']) . ')<br />';
    //Mark it as sent in the DB
}
// Clear all addresses and attachments for next loop
$mail->clearAddresses();
 }   
}
```

Comment: *WHERE CLAUSE*: What is `..jobs_list where id..` in  `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list where id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");`?

Comment: That's just selected the last inserted id from the `jobs_list ` table. for the content of the email.

Comment: How It will select? `WHERE id` is not correct. You have not assigned any value for `id`.

Comment: yes, I did it's  `$lastest_id `

Comment: Is it working? Suspicious to me.

Comment: It gets the most recently inserted row from the table. but there is defiantly an issue somewhere, so you might be right.

Comment: use this `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");` instead of `$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list where id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1");`

Comment: And, I don't get why you are using this while loop `while ($row = $load_candidate->fetch()) {`. No use according to your code.

Comment: yes, because if I try to use `while ($row = $load_candidate->fetch()) {` it break the script and nothing gets sent. thats the question :)

Comment: Frankly speaking. You are confused and so am I. Don't be panic. Take deep breath and tell me what you are looking for. There are many noted points which is suspicious to me. *Please Don't Mind*

Comment: sorry. I'm not explaining myself very well. ok, so I'm adding data to a table `jobs_list `, and I simply want to send a notification email all the users (user table is `candidates_table `) with the information of what has as been added.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150610/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-bob).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps).

Comment: @Synchro I did look at that. but I wasn't sure how to integrate it using PDO instead of mysqli. and why in that example is it referring to a file for the body of the email? kinda confusing.

Comment: Keeping the message body (or a template) in an external file is pretty normal, but it really doesn't matter - you can get the body from anywhere, it's just a string, and in that example it helps keep the size down as body content embedded in the script would just add confusion. Switching from mysqli to PDO is trivial too, but it rather misses my point that you had made structural errors that are nothing to do with minor implementation differences.

Comment: I see what you mean, good point, well made. However, doesn't answer the question of how to select data from two unrelated tables.

Comment: @Synchro I took your advice and used the mailing list example provided with PHPmailer and modified it. would you mind just having a quick look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert Job List in `job_listing` table. Find, current `job_listing` table id. Fetch it again and find all candidates to send email.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

  require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  include 'db_connect.php';

  $contact_name  = $_POST['contact_name'];

  $latest_job_id = 0;

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO jobs_list (jobTitle, company_name, job_details, salary_info, salary_extra, apply_link, company_email, company_phone, TimeStamp) VALUES (:jobTitle, :company_name, :job_details, :salary_info, :salary_extra, :apply_link, :company_email, :company_phone, NOW())");
  $stmt->bindParam(':jobTitle', $_POST['jobTitle'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':company_name', $_POST['company_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':job_details', $_POST['job_details'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':salary_info', $_POST['salary_info'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':salary_extra', $_POST['salary_extra'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':apply_link', $_POST['apply_link'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':company_email', $_POST['company_email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindParam(':company_phone', $_POST['company_phone'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();

  $latest_job_id = $dbh->lastInsertId(); //@Nana Comments: Get latest Job Listing ID

  if($latest_job_id > 0){

    /*@Nana Comments: If Inserted Successfully, '$latest_job_id' will be greater than 0.*/

    $mail_error_text = ""; //@Nana Comments: If email not sent, then it will store the email address

    /*@Nana Comments: Select recent job listing details.*/
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobs_list WHERE id = :id LIMIT 0, 1");
    $sql->bindParam(':id', $latest_job_id);
    if ($sql->execute()) {

      $sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $mail = new PHPMailer;
      $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
      $mail->Host       = ''; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username   = ''; // SMTP username
      $mail->Password   = ''; // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = ''; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port       = ''; // TCP port to connect to
      $mail->setFrom('', 'sender');

      while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {

        $new_company_email = trim($row['company_email']);
        $new_company_name  = trim($row['company_name']);

        /*@Nana Comments: Select all candidates and send email */
        $load_candidate = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidates_table");
        if ($load_candidate->execute()) {
          $load_candidate->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          while ($row = $load_candidate->fetch()) {
            $mail->addAddress($row['email_address']); // Add a recipient
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'New Vacancy';
            $mail->Body    =  'mail body in here';
            $mail->AltBody = '';
            if(!$mail->send()){
              $mail_error_text .= "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $row["email_address"]) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
            }
            $mail->clearAddresses(); // Clear all addresses for next loop
            $mail->clearAttachments(); // Clear all attachments for next loop
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if($mail_error_text != ""){
      echo "<b>Email not sent to:</b><br>".$mail_error_text;
    }

  } else {
    echo "Job Listing Insertion Fails";
  }
} else {
  echo "access denied";
}?>
```

Comment: There's no need to create a new PHPMailer instance every time around the loop, just re-use it. See [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps)

Comment: This sent the same email 20 times.

Comment: at the moment it's sending it all in one email. How can I send each user one email, would that mean just using a foreach loop?

Comment: This does send a separate message to each address, but it's missing calling `clearAddresses()` at the end of the loop, will cause many duplicates to be sent. You're also not checking the return status of the call to `send()`. Might be easier just to use the example :)

Comment: Hi @bob, sorry was unable to respond you back due to busy schedule. I have updated my code, which will send email to each individual. Have a look.

Comment: Hi @NanaPartykar Thanks, I figured it out and got it working. but it sends some emails, however, after a minute or two, I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway. and it ends the script. probably coz I'm trying to send 300 emails at the same time. so trying to figure out how to queue the emails.